# Efficient 3x3 and 2x2 Determinants in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a large numpy array, `arr`, of shape `(N, D, M, D)` where `D` is either two or three.  The array can be thought of as a block of `(D,D)` matrices blocked together in the `N` and `M` dimensions.  I wish to take the determinant of each of these `(D,D)` matrices:

```
out = np.empty((N,M))
for i in xrange(N):
    for j in xrange(M):
        out[i,j] = np.linalg.det(arr[i,:,j,:])
```

The only problem is that `np.linalg.det` does not special-case small matrices and so does a complete BLAS call and LU factorization for each block.  Indeed, for a 2 by 2 matrix `np.linalg.det` takes ~40us on my recent Core i7 system.  What are my options for improving the performance of this fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify duffymo's point, you can easily exploit the block structure with your own function, using vectorized `numpy` operations. Whether this gives you a speedup may depend on how large M and N are:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(2 * 2 * 2 * 2).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)
>>> a[:,0,:,0] * a[:,1,:,1] - a[:,1,:,0] * a[:,0,:,1]
array([[-4, -4],
       [-4, -4]])
>>> a = numpy.arange(2 * 3 * 2 * 3).reshape(2, 3, 2, 3)
>>> a[:,0,:,0] * a[:,1,:,1] * a[:,2,:,2] + \
    a[:,0,:,1] * a[:,1,:,2] * a[:,2,:,0] + \
    a[:,0,:,2] * a[:,1,:,0] * a[:,2,:,1] - \
    a[:,0,:,0] * a[:,1,:,2] * a[:,2,:,1] - \
    a[:,0,:,1] * a[:,1,:,0] * a[:,2,:,2] - \
    a[:,0,:,2] * a[:,1,:,1] * a[:,2,:,0]
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: Any reason that you opted for 12 muls as opposed to 9?  (You can factor out the first term giving a[:,0,:,0]*(a[:,1,:,1] * a[:,2,:,2] - a[:,1,:,2] * a[:,2,:,1]) etc.)

Comment: @FreddieWitherden, no reason -- I was just too lazy to think about it for more than half a second :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LU decomposition to calculate the determinant of 2x2 or 3x3 matricies.  The formulas are well known.  Why not write your own functions and call them?

Comment: Two reasons: firstly anything I write in Python is going to be a lot slower than anything NumPy may already have in C.  Secondly, I am also interested in exploiting the block structure (to avoid the explicit for loops).

Comment: I don't agree.  A one-line formula in Python is going to be slower than LU decomp?